# Keyframes animation not working when multiple instances of a Component rendered with different props?Width used for animation depends on a prop value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

**So the problem statement is like this** :- I have a progress bar component which takes skillValue as a prop and then based on this prop i have tried to add animation such that on initial load the progress bar animates from 0 to skillValue. 
I will present 2 cases to you first for better understanding of the problem.

CASE1 : **No Animation**. This is the sample CSS code. I make use of the after pseudo element to display the highlighted portion on the bar and it's width is dependant on the prop value. In this scenario suppose I iterate over an array with skill values [90,85,70,75] and display the progressBar component with these values.
In this scenario I am able to see 4 progressBars with varying values as defined in the array with styles also being dynamic.

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;

  ::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    background: ${props => props.color};
    width: ${props => props.skillValue}%;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

CASE 2: **With Animation** Now when I try to implement animations based on the prop values taking the similar prop values eg: [90,85,70,75] what I get is all the instances of progressBar component animate but only upto the value of 75 which is the last element on the array. This is the code with animations. I am not able to figure out how it causes this mixup of instances. Or is this a problem with styled components ?

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;

  ::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    background: ${props => props.color};
    border-radius: 5px;
    animation: skillAnim 2s forwards; 
  }

  @keyframes skillAnim {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      100% {
        width: ${props => props.skillValue}%;
      }
  }
```

Case 1 works perfectly fine but problem only arises in Case 2 when I try it to animate based on dynamic prop values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the ideal way. This is how i managed to do it for now.

This is my component logic.

```
const ProgressBar = ({ className, color, value, skill }) => {
  const [skillValue, setSkillValue] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (skillValue + 3 <= value) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setSkillValue(skillValue + 3);
      }, 30);
    } else {
      setSkillValue(value);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [skillValue, value]);
  return (
    <StyledProgressBar className={className} color={color} value={skillValue}>
      <span className="skill">{skill}</span>
      <span className="skill-value">{skillValue}%</span>
    </StyledProgressBar>
  );
};
```

And the styling logic is:

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;

  ::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    background: ${props => props.color};
    width: ${props => props.value}%;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

This enables skillValue to uniformly update up to the desired value and creates the animation effect for the progress bar.